# Initializing an Array when the length is deciphered in a following IF block

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption, scope

I currently have a method in which I am trying to do something with a byte array. However the length of this byte array is dependant on a parameter of the method. I need to declare the array before the if-else blocks and not in them, otherwise the variable is out of scope.

An example of the method is below:

```
private static byte[] messageFormatting(string bodyText, byte packetType)
{
    int index = 0;
    byte[] messageBody;

    if(packetType == 0x03)
    {
        byte[] RSAEncryptedMessageBody = RSAEncrypt(bodyText);
        messageBody = new byte[(RSAEncryptedMessageBody.Length)];
        Array.Copy(RSAEncryptedMessageBody, messageBody, RSAEncryptedMessageBody.Length);
    }

    else
    {
        messageBody = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bodyText);
    }

    byte[] fullMessage = new byte[(messageBody.Length + 6)];

    //do others things

}
```

I am getting an exception error when executing the method because I can't have an object reference which isn't set to an instance of an object.

I'm taking this to mean I can't do `messageBody = new byte[]` when I've got a blank initialization in the preceding `byte[] messageBody`. But if I remove this declaration, the references below the if-else blocks are out of scope. I don't know the length of `messageBody` before encryption occurs. Any advice?

Comment: Your code snip compiles fine for me. Might want to double check the source of that error. (after I added a return to it that is).

Comment: Throw in some asserts. E.g. does RSAEncrypt return a null ? Also why are you copying the array?

Comment: @Wjdavis5 It compiles fine, but any attempt to run it throws the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception. RSAEncrypt returns a byte array

Comment: Ok, but in your question you specifically state that it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Wjdavis5 ahhh so I did, apologies. I'll update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your error is coming in here:

```
byte[] RSAEncryptedMessageBody = RSAEncrypt(bodyText);
messageBody = new byte[(RSAEncryptedMessageBody.Length)];
```

RSAEncrypredMessageBody is likely null.  What is your RSAEncrypt function doing?

Comment: Upon furthing looking into the errors, it is indeed returning null. I'm getting a RSAEncryption "Bad Length." exception and it's returning null in a try catch. Thanks

Comment: And that's why you don't catch exceptions in library functions and let the caller of those functions do whatever with them